# How to specify inline Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I have used the following code in jQuery datatable, I want to specify the Javascript code for `onClick` event but it gives me the error:

> Warning   TS1005  (JS) ';' expected & (JS) Expression expected.

How to resolve these errors?

I want to call the `confirmDelete` function on selection of delete button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $("#employeeManagement").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "order": [[1, "asc"]],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/EmployeeManagement/DisplayEmployeeData",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": false },
            { "data": "userId", "name": "userId", "autoWidth": false },
            { "data": "employeeName", "name": "employeeName", "width": '20%', "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            { "data": "emailId", "name": "emailId", "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            { "data": "phoneNumber", "name": "phoneNumber", "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            { "data": "region", "name": "region", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            { "data": "department", "name": "department", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            { "data": "designation", "name": "designation", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            { "data": "state", "name": "state", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true },
            {
                data: null, "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a href="/EmployeeManagement/EditEmployee/' + full.userId + '"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt" style="color: dodgerblue;text-decoration:unset;"></span></a>'; }, "autoWidth": false, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "width": "7%"
            },
            {
                data: null, "render": function (data, type, full, row) {
                    return '<a href="/EmployeeManagement/DeleteEmployee/' + full.userId + '" onClick="return ConfirmDelete(this)"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color: red; text-decoration:unset;"></span></a>'; }, "autoWidth": false, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "width": "7%"
            },
        ],
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.Responsive(table);

    var object = { status: false, ele: null };
    function ConfirmDelete(event) {
        if (object.status) { return true; }
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure ?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this record !",
            type: "Warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
        },
            function () {
                object.status = true;
                object.ele = event;

                object.ele.click();
            });
        return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: well there are no quotes around the onclick, you have an issue with how you are building the string

Comment: Yes, How to pass the function to that onClick event with Html

Answer (score 0):

```
return '<a href="/EmployeeManagement/DeleteEmployee/' + full.userId + '" onClick="return ConfirmDelete(this)"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color: red; text-decoration:unset;"></span></a>'; }, "autoWidth": false, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "width": "7%"
```

Comment: When I use the double quotes around the onClick the confirmDelete function is not getting consumed

Comment: Can you please provide that error if you are getting on click? Or can you please show us whole page code.

Comment: Can you please move function and that status variable code out of the document ready?
http://prntscr.com/10cta48